# Turbo broadcast_append_later_to / broadcast_append_later rendering twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I the top of my application template body I have:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :toasts %>
```

Which I use to display messages (https://github.com/excid3/tailwindcss-stimulus-components)

In my controllers I have an update_index patch route so that I can do some updates from the index page. The controller and corresponding turbo rendering works on the UI. In that update_index controller action I have this:

```
@project.broadcast_append_later_to @project, target: 'toasts', partial: 'shared/toast', locals: { user: current_user, type: :notice, message: "Project #{@project.name} Updated" }
```

In this action (for context is it matters this was the first model I added to my app). When I update via that action the toast is displayed as expected. The crazy part here is if I add this same logic to my other models the toast gets appended TWICE every-time.

- I checked the logs and I confirmed that Sidekiq is not firing a job
  twice
- I tried broadcast_append_to vs later and the same result If I
  comment this out both toasts are not displayed on the update so I
  know it's not being triggered somewhere else
- I confirmed that I don't have any broadcasts in my models the exact same line of code in the default update action only displays once
- I have gone through model and controllers and they are almost identical except for the odd items here and there - nothing related to this toast (which simply displays the message passed in)

Some context to perhaps trigger ideas:

- the Project model was the first model I added to the app and the rest came afterwards
- all the other models are descendants of Project directly or indirectly via belong_to / has_many etc.
- the issue only occurs in that update_index action

This seems like a wild goosechase and looking for help - perhaps someone may be able to point me to something obvious I am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you add a `turbo_stream_from` tag twice ‍♂️